Am having a problem with my get request as params sent from react cannot be decerialized by axios into my springboot api
the error message on my api console is  Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; For input string: "undefined"
I have looked into the axios code in my react services.jsx file export const listHymns = (bookId) => axios.get(`${REST_API_BASE_URL}${bookId}/hymns`);
and my controller class in t the api but nothing seems to work
 // Find all hymns belonging to the specific book
    @GetMapping("/{bookId}/hymns")
    public ResponseEntity<APIResponse<List<HymnDto>>> getHymnsByBookId(
            @PathVariable("bookId") Long bookId) {

        List<HymnDto> result = hymnService.getHymnsByBookId(bookId);

        // Builder Design pattern
        APIResponse<List<HymnDto>> responseDTO = APIResponse
                .<List<HymnDto>>builder()
                .status(SUCCESS)
                .results(result)
                .build();


        return new ResponseEntity<>(responseDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
    }



in the browser i can see this   GET http://localhost:8080/api/undefined/hymns where my {bookId} params should be is undefined
